# Make Hubot run preconfigured commands automatically

Tags: coffeescript, cron, hubot, flowdock

I'm using Hubot on flowdock and I'm trying to make Hubot post automatically the respond of a user command.

With the help of https://leanpub.com/automation-and-monitoring-with-hubot/read#leanpub-auto-periodic-task-execution , I've managed to make Hubot talk at a specific time creating a cron.coffee script, so no issues with that.

The thing is that I have another script (*trello.coffee*) that makes Hubot respond to the command "show cards" and I want the result of this command to be posted in a specific time without the need of me telling Hubot to do this.

How exactly can I do this without the need to write another script (ie. *trello.auto.coffee*) and the whole robot.emit -> robot.on procedure?

Answer (score 0):

What about using the http listener?
[This page](https://hubot.github.com/docs/scripting/) has a section for HTTP Listener and has this code example:

```
module.exports = (robot) ->
  robot.router.post '/hubot/chatsecrets/:room', (req, res) ->
    room   = req.params.room
    data   = if req.body.payload? then JSON.parse req.body.payload else req.body
    secret = data.secret

    robot.messageRoom room, "I have a secret: #{secret}"

    res.send 'OK'
```

Would that work?